# It has been three years since & It is three years since

Tags: tense, word-usage

> 1. It has been three years since Vick decided to give new life to old waste materials by re-creating them into sculptures and installations.
> 2. It is three years since Vick decided to give new life to old waste materials by re-creating them into sculptures and installations.

Which sentence sound natural?

Comment: Both *is* and *has been* are fine. *Recreating X into Y*, however, is dubious: Vick does not re-create the materials, he casts already created materials into new forms.  I would use a different verb, such as *shaping* or *reshaping*

Answer (score 2):

(1) is probably more natural, and is certainly more general. (2) seems to emphasize the present-historic tense to the extreme - I will definitely expect to be *right there* in the room in which this statement is true, in the following sentences.

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct, mean exactly the same thing and sound natural.
It's been ages since I last saw him.
It's ages since I last saw him.