# It (is/has been) four years since our family has had a vacation

Tags: present-perfect, present-tense

> 1. It is four years since our family has had a vacation.
> 2. It has been four years since our family has had a vacation.

What is the difference between these two sentences? And why is sentence 1 even correct, since we usually use the construction "has been+since/for"? I checked a [similar question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/29486/122691) on this site, but that question doesn't tell the difference and doesn't tell why #1 is correct.

Comment: Related (but not a duplicate) https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/124395/9161

Comment: Also related: https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/76529/9161

Comment: I didn't see your comment when I was posting my answer. If I *had*, I probably wouldn't have answered, because ***it looks like a dup to me***. Can you explain ***why*** you don't think it's a dup? Also for the second one you've just posted here - my inclination is to close *both* the later ones in favour of the first.

Comment: Also related (dup?) [It has been three years since & It is three years since.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/29486/it-has-been-three-years-since-it-is-three-years-since?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Also related [tense usage: “It has been (is) two weeks since I've seen (last saw) you”.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/69031/tense-usage-it-has-been-is-two-weeks-since-ive-seen-last-saw-you) And probably several more!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is yet another one of those situations where [usage has changed over time...](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=it%20is%20years%20since%2Cit%20has%20been%20years%20since&year_start=1860&year_end=2010&corpus=26&smoothing=3)

[image]

Offhand I can't think of any context where it actually makes any *difference* which verb form you use in this context. And I must admit it seems somewhat counter-intuitive that English increasingly favours the *more complex* construction. But there it is - it's essentially a ***stylistic choice***.

---

I'm not quite sure how to explain ***why*** Present Tense is okay here - to me, it's so obviously natural I find it hard to think of needing to *justify* the usage. But perhaps it would help to compare, say,...

> *Come and get it! Your breakfast **is** cooked*
> and
> *...Your breakfast **has been** cooked*

Comment: The reason it has changed may be that saying “It is three years...” puts people in the wrong frame of mind for the rest of the sentence. “It has been three years...” makes it easier to guess what the rest of the sentence is about so we can tune out and go back to reading Twitter ;)

Comment: If that's supposed to "explain" why people prefer the perfect form, how do we account for the fact that people obviously ***didn't*** think like that until a century ago? Actually, I've just realised that I accidentally linked to the NGram chart for the ***American*** corpus. Switching to [the ***British*** corpus](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is+years+since%2Chas+been+years+since&year_start=1860&year_end=2010&corpus=29&smoothing=3), it seems we haven't even yet *reached* the "tipping point" that happened in the US before WW2.

Comment: I don’t think your ngram is giving you the full story (not my downvote btw) the instances are not the same  construction, They’re more like *...that is, years since Mohammad's flight from Mecca in 622 C.E.* It might be better to use something like “it is years since” The search for `it is * since` is interesting.

Comment: Maybe whoever *did* downvote was following the same reasoning as you. I never thought the number of false matches would be significant here (that would imply an even *more* curious "usage change over time" than the simple one being investigated here. Anyway, I've added ***it*** to the front of my search strings to eliminate practically all false matches, and switched to "combined" corpus". The chart still looks much the same, so there's no reason to change any of the text.

Comment: The matches look a lot better. I think it’s likely someone looked at the first few matches of the previous search and saw they didn’t match and that caused the DV.